# How to pass local variable to Invoke-Command's -ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell-3.0, remote-server, invoke-command, scriptblock

I am trying to execute following PowerShell script from Server-2 against Server-1 (i.e. Remote server):

```
$DBServer = 'Server1' 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DBServer -ScriptBlock {
$status = Start-Process "C:\Program Files\iQ4bis\HaloSource\HaloSource.Run.exe" '"D:\Test\UsageTracking.iqp" /wf "Default Workflow" /e "Dev" ' -Wait -PassThru
$test2 = $status.ExitCode
if ($test2 -ne 0) 
{ 
    Throw "The command exited with error code: $test2"
}
else
{
    Write-host "Workflow executed successfully."    
}
}
```

Question: Code part

```
"C:\Program Files\iQ4bis\HaloSource\HaloSource.Run.exe" '"D:\Test\UsageTracking.iqp" /wf "Default Workflow" /e "Dev" ' -Wait -PassThru
```

I wanted to make it parameterized, as values for `D:\Test\UsageTracking.iqp` and `Dev` is going to change per project. How can I pass in new values using parameter? This is the how I wanted it if possible:

```
clear-host

$DBServer = 'Server1'
$v1 = 'D:\Test\UsageTracking.iqp'
$v2 = 'Dev'
$v3 = "C:\Program Files\iQ4bis\HaloSource\HaloSource.Run.exe"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DBServer -ScriptBlock {
param(
[string] $IQPFileDestinationLocation = $v1, [string] $ExecutionEnvironment = $v2, [string] $exe = $v3
)

$IQPFileLocation = $IQPFileDestinationLocation
$workflow = "Default Workflow"
$environment = $ExecutionEnvironment
$test = """$exe"" '""$IQPFileLocation"" /wf ""$workflow"" /e ""$environment""'"
$test

$status = Start-Process $test -Wait -PassThru

$test2 = $status.ExitCode
if ($test2 -ne 0) 
{ 
    Throw "The command exited with error code: $test2"
}
else
{
    Write-host "It went ok."    
}

} -ArgumentList $v1 ,$v2 ,$v3
```

When I run above, I get following error message:

```
    This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
    + PSComputerName        : ken-dev-bi001

The command exited with error code: 
At line:8 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DBServer -ScriptBlock {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (The command exited with error code: :String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The command exited with error code:
```

any help would be appriciated to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,
So, finally I figured it out how to pass local variable to `-ScriptBlock` while using with the `Invoke-Command`against the remote server. 

Here is the code I used and it worked like a charm:

```
Write-Host "Workflow command was: "$HaloSourceCommandLine

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DBServer -ScriptBlock {
param ([string] $t1 = $HaloSourceCommandLine, [string] $t2 = $HaloSourceExecutableLocation)

    $status = Start-Process $t2 $t1 -Wait -PassThru
    $ExitCodeInfo = $status.ExitCode
        if ($ExitCodeInfo -ne 0) 
        { 
            Throw "The command exited with error code: $test2"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-host "Workflow executed successfully."    
        }
} -ArgumentList $HaloSourceCommandLine,$HaloSourceExecutableLocation
```

Hopefully this will help to others if they are having issue executing `-ScriptBlock` against remote server via `Invoke-Command`

Thanks,
HP

Answer (score 1):

I will not implement your code but will explain through a simple example so that you can implement it accordingly.

Suppose you need to start a website hosted on IIS. I have declared the variables. In the function u can assign values to variables as, it should have been like this, instead of  $args[0],
 it should have been $abc, but I have I assigned the value of variable runtime. u can also assign multiple values by separating it with a comma, like

-ScriptBlock {Start-Website $args[0] $args[1]} -ArgumentList $xyz, $abc

```
Code Snippet

   $User="UserName"
   $Password="password"
   $abc="MyWebsite"
   $xyz="MyWebsite2"
   $ComputerName = "MyComputerName"
   $pword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
   $credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User, $pword

   function StartIIS($abc)
   { 
     Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {Start-Website $args[0]} ArgumentList $abc
   }  

   StartIIS($abc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Response to a very old post but it was a top search result so I thought an update would be appropriate.

The very simple way to do this in PowerShell 3.0+ is to use the "Using" scope on any local variable that you want to pass to the remote computer in your -ScriptBlock.  The sample code below is using this on the local "$UpdateFilePath" variable.

```
$SoftwarePackage = [code to find current software exe file]

$UpdateFilePath = "C:\Install\$SoftwarePackage" 
   
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $RemoteComputerName -ScriptBlock {New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce -Name "UpdateSoftware" -Type String -Value $Using:UpdateFilePath}
```

[Include local variables in a command run on a remote computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?source=recommendations&view=powershell-7.3#example-9-include-local-variables-in-a-command-run-on-a-remote-computer)