# Passing string $variable to invoke-command scriptblock parameter -name

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm currently writing a relatively easy PowerShell script to restart/stop/start a service on a remote machine. Everything is working well up until I decide to pass a `$Service` variable to `-Name` parameter in the `Invoke-Command` Scriptblock. I know I'm doing something wrong or forgetting something but your help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code with the part giving me problems highlighted

```
[CmdletBinding()] Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
  [string]$Server,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$Service) 
get-service -ComputerName $Server -Name "$Service"

Write-Host("------------------------------------------------")
Write-Host("Execute action on selected service: ")
Write-Host("1. Restart service ")
Write-Host("2. Stop service ")
Write-Host("3. Start service")
$choice = Read-Host -Prompt "Your choice"

switch ($choice)
{
    1 {Invoke-command -Computername $Server {Restart-Service -Name "$Service" } }
    2 {Invoke-command -ComputerName $Server {Stop-Service  -Name "$Service" } }
    3 {Invoke-command -ComputerName $Server {Start-Service -Name "$Service" } }
}
```

I have tried:

- Single quotes around $Service
- Double quotes around $Service
- using param([String]$Service) in scriptblock

I keep getting the same error over and over:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Stop-Service], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopServiceCommand
```

I know it has to do with the fact Im trying to run local variable on a remote machine. but could someone point me in the right direction , I would love for the script to simply use the mandatory parameters

Using the approach mentionned here [How to pass local variable to Invoke-Command's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339616/) I modified the code like so:

```
1 {Invoke-command -Computername $Server {param ([string] $srv = $Service) Restart-Service -Name "$srv" } }
```

Unfortunately the error persists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass variables with the Invoke-Command cmdlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328690) and [How to pass local variable to invoke commands scriptblock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339616/) and [PowerShell passing variables to remote script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036327/) and [PowerShell passing arguments to invoke command in a foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858282/)

Comment: similar yes, and yes I have tried that approach. It keeps returning that the -Name parameter is an empty string

Comment: tried the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339616/ approach same effect keeps returning Empty string error

Answer (score 5):

the syntax for parameter passing into a scriptblock should be as follows:

(Corrected as @pk198105 suggested)

```
Invoke-command -Computername $Server  {
param($service)
Restart-Service -Name "$Service" 
} -ArgumentList $service
```

both argumentlist and param are required

Comment: nope doesnt work. sorry

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks in part to Abhijith pk

the correct way to implement this is as follows:

```
Invoke-command -Computername $Server  {param ($Service) Restart-Service -Name "$service" } -ArgumentList $service
```

Thank you

Comment: This looks the same as your other answer with the arguments moved around

Comment: yes Abhijith answer the arguments were in the wrong position