# Powershell - Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to stop a remote service using this Powershell script:

```
$hostname1 = "myhost"
$serviceName = "myservice"
Write-Host "Hostname: $hostname1"
Write-Host "Service name: $serviceName"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname1 -ScriptBlock {
  Stop-Service -Name $serviceName -Force
}
```

But getting this error message:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Stop-Service], ParameterBindin
   gValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,M icrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopServiceCommand
```

If I remove `Invoke-Command` from the script, I can see the variables are initialized correctly:

```
$hostname1 = "myhost"
$serviceName = "myservice"
Write-Host "Hostname: $hostname1"
Write-Host "Service name: $serviceName"
```

Returns:

```
Hostname: myhost
Service name: myservice
```

What can be a reason for this?

Thanks,
Roman

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass variables with the Invoke-Command cmdlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328690/how-do-i-pass-variables-with-the-invoke-command-cmdlet)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339616/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036327/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858282/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was stuck and as soon I posted my question I found an answer myself.

Answer (score 4):

A little bit of further digging and I found the answer myself - need to use `-argumentlist`

```
$hostname1 = "myhost"
$serviceName = "myservice"
Write-Host "Hostname: $hostname1"
Write-Host "Service name: $serviceName"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname1 -ScriptBlock {
  Stop-Service -Name $args[0] -Force
} -argumentlist $serviceName
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution
 Please use the automatic variable '$using'.

```
$hostname1 = "myhost"
$serviceName = "myservice"
Write-Host "Hostname: $hostname1"
Write-Host "Service name: $serviceName"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname1 -ScriptBlock {
  Stop-Service -Name $Using:ServiceName -Force
}
```